# Re-assign id numbers in sorted table

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

i'm looking for solution to my problem.

I need to reassign id's in that order in which that table is sorted.

To be more clear here is the how table look:

### |   id   |   name   |  new_id  |

### |   1    |    C     |     1    |

### |   2    |    A     |     2    |

### |   3    |    B     |     3    |

> Now we sort it by name in ASC mode:

### |   id   |   name   |  new_id  |

### |   2    |    A     |     2    |

### |   3    |    B     |     3    |

### |   1    |    C     |     1    |

> Now we reassign id's in that order:

### |   id   |   name   |  new_id  |

### |   1    |    A     |     2    |

### |   2    |    B     |     3    |

### |   3    |    C     |     1    |

I use this code:

```
set @row_num = 0; SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as `row_number`,`id`,`name`,`new_id` FROM `test` ORDER BY `name`;
```

it add new row row_number and add numbers in order that i need for id to be. How to do this.

Comment: can you explain why you feel the need to do this (or re-do it perpetually)

Comment: The role of a unique ID is solely to uniquely identify a row.  It is not meant to have any intrinsic meaning.  You already know you can ORDER then however you want for display or processing.  In a more complex DB, it is a very, very bad idea to reassign IDs because other rows will be using that *unique Id* to identify specific rows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a horrible idea that will mess up your data most likely

Comment: oh, snap. i made a mistake sorry, the real question is how to reassign new_id not the id.

Comment: @Drew well i have in table in row name a same names e.g. A, A, B, C, B, A.. and after sorting it A, A, A, B, B, C i need to reassign new_id to look like A - 1, A - 2, A - 3, B - 4, B - 5, C - 6, and after in report i will select new_id from 1 - 3 and it will show me only A's in report.

Comment: fair enough. Good luck :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `update`:

```
set @rn := 0;
update t
    set new_id = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    order by name;
```

You don't really need to use `new_id`.  If you want to re-set `id`, just set that instead.